# How to delete specific lines within a certain area?

Tags: awk, sed

I want to delete some specific lines in the YAML front matter:

```
---
Author: aaaa
Title: bbbb
Time: cccc
Place: dddd
...
```

Lets say I wanted to delete only the lines in the front matter that contained "title:" and "place:"

To make sure I am not deleting any other lines that contain these words, it should only search the front matter. Also any solution would preferably not use the line number but rather the actual word as its criteria for selection.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

---

My own research consists of:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049962/delete-line-containing-different-strings) - which deletes multiple words in one go

[and This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221779/can-i-use-sed-or-something-to-remove-yaml-frontmatter-from-markdown-files) - which selects a specific area of the file

Comment: What delimits the "front matter"? can you show more of your YAML file to see what should be kept?

Comment: `sed '/^Title: \|^Place: /d' file.txt `?

Comment: HI I have edited the Front matter in my question to show what delimits it.  How do i use this command to only apply within the front matter?

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with the `YFM` (`YAML front matter`) but [as per this page](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) it *must be the first thing in the file and must take the form of valid YAML set between triple-dashed lines*. That means your file will always start with `---` if `YFM` is present, so you could run:

```
sed -n '1{/^---$/!q};1,/^---$/{/^Title: \|^Place: /d};p' infile
```

i.e. if the first line doesn't match `---` `q`uit, otherwise `d`elete all lines matching those patterns if they occur between the `1`st line and the next line matching `---`
If the second marker is `...` just alter the second `sed` expression but note that to match a literal dot you'll have to escape it e.g. to match `...` you would use `\.\.\.` or `\.\{3\}`):

```
sed -n '1{/^---$/!q};1,/^\.\.\.$/{/^Title: \|^Place: /d};p' infile
```

Comment: What if the front matter ends in `...`, would the command be `sed -n '1{/^---$/!q};1,/^...$/{/^Title: \|^Place: /d};p' infile` ??

Comment: @stjohnsmith - almost there, you just have to escape the dots if they are to be matched literally. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to heemayl's sed solution, also a grep option:

```
grep -Ev '^Title:|^Place:' file.txt
```

Explanation:

- grep -v to ignore lines that include Title: or Place:
- grep -E to stack the two terms
- ^ indicates the patterns should be at the
  beginning of the line

Comment: How do you apply this only to the front matter?? Please see my edition of the question which shows what delimits the front matter.